# How to drop user without table in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-drop, drop-table

How can I drop user without the table in oracle?

```
 create user andi identified by andi; 
 alter user andi quota 10m on users; 
 grant connect to andi; 
 grant create table to andi;

 conn andi;

 create table mahasiswa( idmhs number(3) primary key, nama varchar(20),
    nim number(7), jurusan varchar(20) );

 insert into mahasiswa values (101, 'Budi', 0881103, 'TI');

 drop user andi cascade; ---> table mahasiswa is also deleted.
```

How can I drop user without the table in oracle?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this.

The table belongs to andi and **when you drop andi you also drop all its belongings**.

As mentioned before (by @Steven Wolfe) create a user for the tables, and grant privileges for the other users.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the `mahasiswa` table with another user as the owner and then grant the user `andi` whichever privileges they require (`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`).

I'd also create a synonym so you don't have to continually reference the table from the `andi` schema with the owner schema, eg: `OTHERUSER.mahasiswa`. As the `andi` user execute the following:

```
CREATE SYNONYM mahasiswa FOR OTHERUSER.mahasiswa
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i created 'CREATE SYNONYM mahasiswa FOR OTHERUSER.mahasiswa' from user andi? but it said insufficient privileges..
so i create 'grant create synonym to andi' from dba. name is already used by an existing object but i dont have any table mahasiswa on the dba user..

Comment: @Grace You should create the synonym within the schema which will access the object referenced by the synonym, or you can `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` which can be visible by any user (schema).